# No executable file after building in Release mode in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw, release

I am trying to build my project in Release mode, and I am using eclipse, but for some reason it doesn't generate the executable file.

I can run the program in eclipse (in Release mode), but I want to check the executable in the workspace folder. In Debug mode, it generates it normally, but in Release mode it doesn't seem to be...
I tried cleaning the project still doesn't generate.

What could the problem be ?
Note: nothing wrong with the program, as it runs normally in eclipse, it just doesn't generate the exe file.

Any solution XD ?
Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

please check the target path in the release configuration of the project.Debug and release have different configuration may be the path isn't correct in release configuration.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it has the same path as Debug, because it generates the folder and the object files, but just doesn't generate executable :/
Could it generate it separately somewhere else ?